# Después de recargar un div con load, no funciona onclick de jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tengo un botón en mi iteración que con el `data-id` modifico cada linea de la iteración en la base de datos, una modificado recargo el div con `load` pero la pantalla aparece todo bien, pero en cambio el botón no funciona.

```
<div class="contenidoPedido" id="">
    <ul>
      @foreach ($mesas as $item)
        <li>
          {{ $item->mesa }}
        </li>
        @foreach ($item->pedidos->groupBy('ticket') as $key => $peds)
           <div class="modulOrder" id="ped_{{ $key }}">
             <span class="indicaPed"><b>{{ $key }}</b></span>
             <hr>
             @foreach ($peds as $item5)
               <div class="fondoPed1">
                 <div class="paraPoint">
                    <div class="tituProducto">{{ $item5->producto }} @if(!$item5->opcion == null) - {{ $item5->opcion }} @endif</div>
                    <div class="subsProducto"><b>CANTIDAD: </b> {{ $item5->cantidad }}</div>
                    <a class="btnListo" data-id="{{ $item5->id }}" data-ticket="{{ $item5->ticket }}">LISTO {{ $item5->id }}</a>
                 </div>
               </div>
             @endforeach 
           </div> 
         @endforeach
      @endforeach
     </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Luego con onclick obtengo el data-id del botón que pulso**

```
$(".btnListo").on('click', function() {
    var idProducto = $(this).data("id");
    var ticket = $(this).data("ticket");
    console.log(idProducto);
});
```

Pero solo me funciona una vez, una vez ejecutado y actualizado ya no funciona.

Comment: Cuando se carga la página, el botón existe y se puede asignar el evento. Luego remplazas el contenido y el navegador interpreta todo de nuevo; el botón que aparece no es el mismo que estaba originalmente y es por eso que ya no tiene el evento. La solución propuesta en la respuesta que te dieron es muy buena, porque se ["delega"](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) el evento al contenedor padre y no importa si el botón existía o apareció posteriormente.

Comment: Gracias @Triby ya lo probe y funciona perfecto!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
$(".contenidoPedido").on('click', 'a.btnListo',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    var idProducto = $(this).data("id");
    var ticket = $(this).data("ticket");
    console.log(idProducto);
});
```

De esta forma estarás "bindeando el evento click a todas las etiquetas a con clase "btnListo" que se encuentran dentro del div contenidoPedido. Parece lo mismo pero no, el contenido dinámico agregado como parte de una respuesta Ajax, mantendrá el enlace a los eventos definidos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Francisco funciono perfecto!!